# Exclude a node module's tests from Android React Native app

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, junit

I have a module being included in my application that is failing tests and causing my CI build to fail.

I have tried excluding the tests in my `app/build.gradle` with the following, but it is not successfully excluding the tests:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        test {
            java {
                srcDir 'src'
                exclude 'com/some/path/**'
            }
        }
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

Alternatively, I've looked for a way to just delete, in an automated way, the `test` folder for the module, but I haven't found anything.

Comment: why do you have `android { sourceSets { test { java {` Shouldn't it be just `test { exclude 'com/some/path/**' }` in the root of `build.gradle`?

Comment: That's where I started @PanagiotisBougioukos, but Android's gradle implementation does not honor that functionality.